# Can't retrieve the name of the file with ACF on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, filenames, advanced-custom-fields

I'm on Wordpress using the `ACF plugin` and I can't display the name of the `file`. I have tried several ways, from different sites, to do this and nothing works. I even use the code shown here http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/file/.

I have no problem retrieving the files, but I found its impossible to retrieve the file's name!

My code is

```
<?php           
$group_ID = 26; //video
$video_field = array();
$video_field = apply_filters('acf/field_group/get_fields', $video_field, $group_ID);

if ($video_field) {
    foreach ($video_field as $field) {
        $value_video = get_field( $field['name'] );
        $title_video = get_field( $field['filename'] );

        if($value_video == "") { }
        else { ?>
            <h2><?php echo $title_video['filename']; ?></h2><br>
                <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                    <source src="<?php echo $value_video ;?>" type="video/mp4">
                </video><?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I made a var_dump of the $field and this is what it shows

```
bool(false)
array(14) { 
["key"]=> string(19) "field_56293fd283256" 
["label"]=> string(6) "Video1" 
["name"]=> string(6) "video1" 
["_name"]=> string(6) "video1" 
["type"]=> string(4) "file" 
["order_no"]=> int(0) 
["instructions"]=> string(14) "Video tutorial" 
["required"]=> int(0) 
["id"]=> string(16) "acf-field-video1" 
["class"]=> string(4) "file" 
["conditional_logic"]=> array(3) { 
["status"]=> int(0) 
["rules"]=> array(1) { 
[0]=> array(2) { 
["field"]=> string(4) "null" 
["operator"]=> string(2) "==" } } 
["allorany"]=> string(3) "all" } 
["save_format"]=> string(3) "url" 
["library"]=> string(10) "uploadedTo" 
["field_group"]=> int(26)
```

and now, I'm seing that the reason that why is not retrieven the file name, it's because it's not there, but why? The name of this file is **video_1**

Comment: Please let us know the output of `$field` inside **foreach** loop.

Comment: Good job. Always dump the data before use.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's my fault, but can you point out what do you exactly mean by filename and name with an example?